# How to Increase/Configure Snippet size of a highlight?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I want to know that how we can configure Snippet Size(number of words/Characters) in highlighting? Currently i m facing a problem, sometimes solr Gives me snippet exactly the matched word. like let say I query solr as "Contents:risk" using solrnet it gives me exactly "risk" in highlighting snippets no more characters or words i do the same with Solr admin and it gives the same result too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not quite familiar with highlighting features but I believe this is done with the [**hl.fragsize**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragsize) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Mauricio already answered and this is a little bit of an old thread, but just to add the solution using SolrNet it would be:

- Create a new Highlighting parameters object.
- Set fragsize
- Other parameters are possible
- Highlighting documentation can be found here: [Highlighting.md](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Highlighting.md)

Here is a sample code:

```
 private HighlightingParameters SetHighLightSnippetParameters()
        {
            return new HighlightingParameters
            {
                Fragsize = SearchConstants.SnippetSize
            };
        }
```